# Which Macbooks charge the fastest?

Tags: battery

Is there any difference in the number of hours different generations and models of MacBooks take to "fast-charge" to 80%, or to fully charge?

Comment: Your question has gotten some flags for low quality - please have a look at our guide on [ask] - especially the homework, specific and relevant sections. Are you instead looking where to look up battery capacities for specific models (and each and every of the dozen MacBook) or are you looking to debunk something someone wrote or skeptical of Apple's claims that all their batteries charge the same overall.

Comment: It's also OK to ask a very vague question, since others may edit it or show up with a nice answer - but generally you want to comment or edit to say you know this is vague and want an overview if you really don't have a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

All Apple products tend to finish the quick charge in just under 2 hours and reach full charge capacity just after 4 hours have passed.

Look at http://www.apple.com/batteries/ where this nice chart explains the charging curves in terms of voltage rise and current flow over time from empty to full.

[image: Apple's depiction of LiPo charging]

As your battery ages, the charging does deviate from this curve and of course the 85 Watt adapter on a 15"/17" MacBook Pro is sending more current to a larger battery, but in the end, the stock new charging performance of all Apple products (iOS/iPod/portable) are designed to meet these times by changing the internal circuitry and power sources.

Faster charging is clearly possible, but degrades the life of the battery so my observation is that Apple controls the charge rate by having a charge controller that slows it down to meet these target times.